# Data after Saving not showing on DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

This is my service in MVVM. The data is added to the list and can see it in debugger but just before showing it on UI Presentation it did not show. i had applied two way binding and have use DataGridView. its showing data on the LoadData function but not loading. i am starter to the WPF

```
        public EmployeeViewModel()
        {
            CurrentEmployee = new Employee();
            objEmployeeService = new EmployeeService();
            saveCommand = new RelayCommand(Save);
            LoadData();
           
        }
        private void LoadData()
        {
            obj_Employee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(objEmployeeService.GetAllEmployees());
        }
        #endregion

        #region AddEmployee
        private Employee currentEmployee;
        private string message;
        public string Message { get { return message; } set { message = value; OnPropertyChanged("Message"); } }
        public Employee CurrentEmployee
        {
            get { return currentEmployee; }
            set { currentEmployee = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentEmployee"); }
        }

        private RelayCommand saveCommand;
        public RelayCommand SaveCommand
        {
            get { return saveCommand; }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            bool IsSaved=false;
            try
            {
                IsSaved = objEmployeeService.Add(CurrentEmployee);
                LoadData();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Message = ex.Message;
            }
            if (IsSaved)
                Message = "Employee Saved";
        }
```

Here is my UI

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgridEmployees" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Grid.Row="6"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Margin="3"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Employees, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="EmployeeID"
                                    Width="auto"
                                    Binding=
                                    "{Binding Path=Id}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name"
                                    Width="auto"
                                    Binding=
                                    "{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="EmployeeAge"
                                    Width="auto"
                                    Binding=
                                    "{Binding Path=Age}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: The Binding of an ItemsSource property is always OneWay. Setting it to TwoWay has no effect. Besides that, it is not clear how this is supposed to work at all, since there is apparently no Employees property anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

It does not appear that this binding goes anywhere...what is `Employees`>

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Employees, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

You only show `obj_Employee` being set. Maybe bind to that?

---

As to a **re**-load, ...sometimes the control needs to be signaled to announce a change after an initial bind. This is sometimes done by setting the initial binding target to null first, and then set to the new reference. Add this into your load:

```
obj_Employee = null;
obj_Employee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(objEmployeeService.GetAllEmployees());
```